# SAS filevar with multiple variables and the meaning of fileref

Tags: file, sas, ref

I recently found out about the filevar statement. Is it possible to use this to write various text files split by multiple variables? All the examples i've seen online have only written to text files based on a single variable they want to split by.

For example: Suppose I have a dataset about cars that contains a character variable about the color, a character variable detailing the make of car, and a numeric variable detailing the year of purchase.

Could I then use filevar to write multiple text files split by all of these variables at once (possibly by concatenation of them within a filepath and then set this filepath as a fileref)? So i'd get one text file that has make= A, color=Red, year=2000. A second text file that has make=A, color=Blue, year= 2000 etc.

Also i keep seeing the word fileref but no clear explanation of what is actually is. Intuitvely I get the feeling that it is just an alias for the name of a file that we can refer to in code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the `fileref` as the pointer to the file, ala C/C++.

You absolutely can drive file output using the values from a data set.  Here is an example using the first few observations from the `SASHELP.CARS` data.

```
proc sort data=sashelp.cars (where=(make in ('Acura', 'Audi', 'BMW')))
          out=cars;
by make type;
run;

data _null_;
set cars;
by make type;
retain fid;
if first.type then do;
    f_name = catt("c:\temp\",make,"_",type,".txt");
    rc = filename("temp",f_name);
    fid= fopen("temp","o");
    rc = fput(fid,'make,model,type,msrp');
    rc = fappend(fid);
end;

rc = fput(fid,catx(",",make,model,type,msrp));
rc = fappend(fid);

if last.type then do;
    rc = fclose(fid);
end;
run;
```

This generates a CSV file for each `MAKE, TYPE` group listing the car name and MSRP.

For each group:

1. `f_name` is the physical file name for the output. the `filename()`
   and `fopen()` functions open the file for output.  `fid` is the
   reference to the file.
2. `fput()` puts a line into the buffer.
3. `fappend()` appends the buffer to the file.  Do this for the header
   and then once for each record.
4. at the end of the group, close the
   file with `fclose()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can follow this up to the f_name line and then don't understand what is happening. (Is fid a hidden variable that SAS uses?). In the rc=filename(...) is temp your fileref? Wat does the second parameter in filename represent (the SAS documentation i haven't found very useful). Apologies for all the questions, new to this type of SAS.

Comment: `fid` is the pointer variable.  I will add a little more to the answer.

Comment: This is a good example, but it seems like overkill doesn't it (since you can use `filevar` to do this with normal file i/o)?

Comment: Thanks! Is fid an arbitrary name or does SAS always use this name? After googling i've come across f_id, so i'm assuming it's just an arbitrary pointer name?

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right; you can use `filevar` to define the filename based on the data in your dataset.

Here's a trivial example, using `sashelp.cars` to make a set of files, one per car make.

```
filename a temp;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.cars;
  outname = cats('c:\temp\',make,'.txt');
  file a filevar=outname dlm=',';
  put make $ model $ mpg_city mpg_highway;
run;
```

The `a` filename is a junk filename - it is there because it has to have something in that spot in the syntax.  It doesn't do anything (hence the `temp`).

Things to note: using this method, you have to have a file sorted properly (in groups that correspond to your files).  Otherwise it will not work the way you want it to.  It doesn't have to be in *order* by that variable, but it has to be *arranged* by that variable.  So this is fine:

```
A
A
B
B
G
G
C
C
D
D
```

But not this:

```
A
B
G
C
D
A
B
G
C
D
```

You also have to make sure you have legal filenames (so don't use `model` in `sashelp.cars` unless you clean it up, as it has lots of illegal characters like `\` in it).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could I extend this though so that it was say outname= cats('c:\temp\',make,color,prodyear'.txt');  in order to split the files into make colour and year of production all in one file. And then loop through all possibly combinations? Never had to use files in SAS before and i'm a fairly novice programmer. Apologies for silly questions.

Comment: Sure, you absolutely could (you'd get a lot of files, of course).  You don't have to do any looping, the data step does that for you.  As long as `outname` becomes a legal filename, and the data is organized so that any set of records you want output to a single file is all grouped together before you output it, you're fine.

Comment: Data does not need to be grouped in advance. SAS will just open and close the file as the generated filename changes.

Comment: @Tom While SAS will happily do so, it will not append; compare my example to an identical one except with CARS sorted by Model (changing the input).  Acura then for example haws 2 rows instead of 7 in it (as the last mention of Acura has 2 consecutive).

Comment: I have used FILE statement to write to multiple files when data is not sorted many times. You probably need to include the `MOD` option.

Comment: There is no need for the FILENAME statement.  You can still use any word you want in the FILE statement where you have `A` since it is not really going to be used.

Comment: Sure, I put it there to make it clear to the programmer that it’s not a real file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the `FILEVAR=` option on the `FILE` statement. This tells SAS to use the value of a particular variable to find the name of the file to write into.  You can build it from anything you want.

A `fileref` is the alias that you create when you use the `FILENAME` statement or `FILENAME()` function. Just like a `libref` is the alias that you create when you use the `LIBNAME` statement or `LIBNAME()` function.

So you can define a fileref that points to one or more files.

```
filename file1 '/project1/source.csv';
filename file2 ('/project1/source1.txt' '/project1/source2.txt');
```

And then you can use the fileref in places you might have previously used a quoted physical filename.

```
infile file1 dsd ;
infile file2 eov=eov ;
```

You can also use fileref's to point to directories.

```
filename raw '/project1/' ;
```

And then add `()` to reference specific files within those directories.

```
infile raw('source.csv') dsd ;
infile raw('source1.txt' 'source2.txt') eov=eov;
file raw('export.csv') dsd ;
```